# warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I get the ff error when i run flutter run.

```
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
error: warnings found and -Werror specified

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

This is my flutter doctor output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1139], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (8 weeks ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USER01\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

I cant seem to find anything on google. How do i fix this error ?

Answer (score 14):

This is a warning about the compiler targeting an older version of Java (7 in this case) that will be deprecated soon.

To fix this you have two options:

1. You can set your `JAVA_HOME` to an older version of Java and then run your Flutter build. You would also need to have this `JAVA_HOME` available anywhere you build from (command line, IDE, CI/CD, etc)
2. Or my preferred way is to tell Gradle to use an older Java toolchain for compiling Java source.

To do option 2, update your `allprojects` section of `android/build.gradle` to look like the following:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    javaCompiler = javaToolchains.compilerFor {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
    }
  }
}
```

This includes an update to change the deprecated `jcenter` Maven repository.

EDIT Nov 2021: Support for toolchains has also been added to the Kotlin Gradle plugin.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/11/gradle-jvm-toolchain-support-in-the-kotlin-plugin/

Comment: There is no `JavaLanguageVersion.of()` in my case, there is only `kotlin_version`, could you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @SonXuanNguyen this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65543854/176496

Answer (score 8):

Try doing this
`Android Studio -> File -> Invalid cache and restart`

Comment: So simple but seems to help.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a fix but a temporary workaround. Put the following in your `build.gradle`, under the `allprojects{}` section:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-options' 
}
```

If your Android java code is the unmodified default generated code, then the bug is with one of your dependencies, you will have to go through `pubspec.yaml` and find the library that is causing the error.

Comment: I am using Flutter and got the above error message. This fixed it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with some Android project. There are two build.gradle files, one in the top level folder, and one inside `app/`. I fixed it by editing the file inside `app/` like so:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

I changed it from `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem in Sep 2021 with Flutter 2.6.0 and VSCode on a Mac, and none of the project-level solutions above worked for me.  I tried a bunch of stuff:

- setting java.home in launch.json
- setting JAVA_HOME in settings.json
- all the build.gradle suggestions above
- using jenv to set java locally for the project dir
- installing the RedHat Java VSCode extension and fiddling with various settings there

Nothing project-specific worked for me.  However, using jenv to set my **global** java version to jdk 11 did fix the problem, albeit with a sledgehammer.